# Iphone simulator asking for passcode instead of faceid

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, face-id

so I have two problems

firstly when I call this `let compatible = await LocalAuthentication.hasHardwareAsync()` it returns `false` even though I have Features > FaceID > enrolled (checked). weirdly when I uncheck it, it returns true :/

secondly, when I call this `let res = await LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync()`

this is showing me the passcode field rather than the faceid, again confused as to why it's showing me that.

in `info.plist` I have enabled faceid by doing this

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allows access to face scanner</string>
```

any ideas why either of these are behaving strangely?

I recently changed my bundle identifier,is there a chance this could have effected it?